# Reduce Docker image size: Python3 and psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux

If I build a docker image for flask deployments I currently use:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy

EXPOSE 5005

ENV FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=5005

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Unfortunately this results in a container with around 500MB size. The original Alpine image was around 40MB.
The main size increase comes from installing psycopg2 and gcc (needed for psycopg2).

I would really like to lower the size of this image. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Use the first stage for building all desired dependencies and the second stage for generating the final Docker image. Just copy the generated site-packages (and other artifacts, if needed) from the build stage to the second one.

So, your Dockerfile might look like this (note the two `FROM` statements):

```
# Build stage:
FROM python:3.6-alpine as build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy

# "Default" stage:
FROM python:3.6-alpine

# Copy generated site-packages from former stage:
COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5005

ENV FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT=5005

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```